# TensorFlow GPU Epoch Optimization?

Tags: python, tensorflow

So this code works, and it gives me a 2x boost over CPU only, but I think its possible to get it faster.  I think the issue boils down to this area...

```
for i in tqdm(range(epochs), ascii=True):
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: train, y_:labels})
```

I think what happens is that every epoch, we go back to the CPU for information on what to do next (the for loop) and the for loop pushes back to the GPU.  Now the GPU can fit the entire data set and more into memory.

Is it possible, and if so how?  to just have it continually crunch 1000 epochs on the GPU without coming back to the CPU to report its status.  Or perhaps control how often it reports status.  It would be nice to say crunch 1000 epochs on GPU, and then see my train vs validation, then crunch again.  But doing it between every epoch is not really helpful.

Thanks,

~David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The overhead of `session.run` is  around 100 usec, so if you do 10k steps, this overhead adds around 1 second. If this is significant, then you are doing many small iterations, and are incurring extra overhead in other places. IE, GPU kernel launch overhead is 5x larger than CPU (5 usec vs 1 usec).

Using `feed_dict` is probably a bigger problem and you could speed things up by using queues/input pipelines.

Also, a robust way to figure out where you are spending time is to profile.
IE, to figure out what fraction of time is due to your `for` loop, you can do cProfile as follows.

```
python -m cProfile -o timing.prof myscript.py
snakeviz  timing.prof
```

To figure out where the time goes inside of TensorFlow `run`, you can do timeline profiling as described [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1824#issuecomment-225754659)

Comment: Does the data queue keep the GPU kernel open?  I think you may be correct here.  Also is it possible to execute the profiling from an IPython type environment?  I do my prototyping in IPython and then ship up for production.  I suppose I could do non IPython, but I really like IPython...

Comment: Youu can do timeline profiling in IPython. The other kind of profiling is not that important, it'll just show you what I said -- 100us spent in session.run . The advantage of using data queue is that all data is kept on TensorFlow side. With feed_dict you have two copies at each step -- one to copy from Python to TensorFlow runtime, and another to transfer to GPU.