# Tensorflow: Efficiently moving/putting data onto the GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow

So I'm reading a bit more about moving data from the CPU -> GPU in Tensorflow, and I see that `feed_dict` is still slow:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2919

The immediate options I see for "moving" Python variables over to the GPU are:

```
#1. Tensorflow constant
a = tf.constant(data, name='a')

#2. Tensorflow Variable
b = tf.Variable(data, name='b')

#3. Tensorflow placeholder
c = tf.placeholder(dtype=dtype, shape=[x,y,z ...], name='c')
```

Options `#1` and `#2` aren't practical for very large dataset variables (since you're actually preloading the data into memory), as we'll quickly exceed the 2GB graph limit. That currently makes `#3` the better choice for getting large *Python* vars into Tensorflow, but then you're forced into using `feed_dict`.

Are there other options for moving *Python variables* to the GPU besides `#1`, `#2`, and `#3`? I'm referring to using...

```
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    # create tensorflow object(s), whether it's tf.Variable, tf.constant, etc
```

If I'm understanding correctly, we can use the input pipeline features to work around this issue? I'm referring to these two here:

1. https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/17559/input-pipeline-for-tensorflow-on-gpu
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38956678/7093236

Is there anything I can do to further enhance the speed of putting everything on the Tensorflow side?

Comment: There's additional trick you can do if you want to overlap GPU access and CPU->GPU transfers, using staging area like [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/benchmarks/blob/21a1facc2ccac5b68186d37d02a0c4708d0fa4fd/scripts/tf_cnn_benchmarks/tf_cnn_benchmarks.py#L1218)

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to use tensorflow [Queue](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/io_ops/queues) to speed up data transfer.

You can do the following step even if you don't have label files

```
# data_files and labels_files are list, this may be some data files path, and labels values.
filename_queue = tf.train.slice_input_producer([data_files, label_files], shuffle=True)   
# filename_queue = tf.train.slice_input_producer(data_files, shuffle=True)       
# Some steps to decode the files and process
 ......
data, label = some_function(filename_queue)

# Define batch size and get batch for processing
image_batch, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch([data, label], batch_size=batch_size, num_threads=num_threads)
```

Comment: Do correct me if I'm wrong, but until at least TF 1.5 I don't believe there is a queue that can be tied to the GPU. Queues only sit on the CPU. Is there any reason to expect a CPU based queue to be faster that the feed_dict method?

Answer (score 1):

The [Dataset API](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/docs_src/programmers_guide/datasets.md) is the future-proof way of moving data to the GPU. All reasonable optimizations, like those explained in the [tensorflow performance guide](http://tensorflow.org/performance), will eventually be available there.

Comment: Eventually is a key word here. As far as I'm aware this is not currently possible using the Dataset in TF 1.4, and I'm not too hopeful that full asynchronous prefetching to the GPU will be in 1.5 either, though I do note that a queue that can reside on the GPU appears slated for 1.5.

Comment: The links give a 404, can you update the correct links?